# Calculate centers of multiple point clusters in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, qr-code

For a task for my image processing course we need to decode a QR code. The first step in this is to find the centers of the alignment blocks. We can find the horzontal an vertical centers of the alignment blocks trough a row and column scan on the ratios, but we want to try to increase accuracy of this by taking the results of multiple line scan actions on different rows in the neighbourhood. Instead of one horizontal scan and one vertical scan.

This results in 3 clusters of multiple points. How can we reduce these 3 clusters to 3 single points in the center of these respective clusters?

[image: QR code after linescan analysis]
 (The stray points in this image will still be filtered by matching it with a vertical scan.)

Comment: As your clusters seem linearly distributed (red: vertical, blue horizontal) I would suggest to calculate the linear regression of both clusters. Then you calculate the intersection of the 2 lines. It seems more robust than calculating the mean or the variance.

Comment: And how could we discern different clusters? Our first idea was to split the image in 4 quadrants, but it is not guaranteed that each alignment block would fall in 1 of the four quadrants of the image.

Comment: If you have some clusters,... you can use a clustering method ! For example the [hierarchical clustering](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/hierarchical-clustering.html). This method is already implemented, you just have to select the good "cutoff" value.